# Stuck at splash screen with mouse pointer after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, screen, plymouth

I am stuck at the Ubuntu splash screen. I recently performed an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. At the first reboot, I am stuck at that splash screen which freezes after the mouse pointer appears at the lower right end of the display.

But booting from recovery works fine but lags like hell. Please help. I am a music producer and I have all my files stored in LMMS.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an older computer with an older GPU, that doesn't like wayland.

Boot to recovery mode, root access.

`sudo mount -o remount,rw /` # change disk to rw mode

`sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit custom.conf file

find the line:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

and change it to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

`reboot` # reboot the computer